# XML Serialization with Framework 2.0 and Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Recently  i have shifted my project from framework 2.0 to framework 4.5.
I have a xml file which will be deserlize and do the some operations. The xml desearlization is ok with the framework 2.0 its working properly. But the same xml file without changing any code any xml file it does not deserlize it give me the error as "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 31, position 27.".  I have wasted 30 min for this.
Here is my XML file

```
<SpreadResultData>
<SpreadToList>
<Spread>
<GroupName>A</GroupName>
<CellPos>B</CellPos>
<CellValue>0~</CellValue>
<Color>Green</Color>
<CellLinePos>3</CellLinePos>
<IsSetColor>true</IsSetColor>
<IsClear>false</IsClear>
</Spread>
<Spread>
<GroupName>B</GroupName>
<CellPos>C</CellPos>
<CellValue>0~</CellValue>
<Color>Yellow</Color>
<CellLinePos>3</CellLinePos>
<IsSetColor>true</IsSetColor>
<IsClear>false</IsClear>
</Spread>
<Spread>
<GroupName>C</GroupName>
<CellPos>D</CellPos>
<CellValue>0~</CellValue>
<Color>Red</Color>
<CellLinePos>3</CellLinePos>
<IsSetColor>true</IsSetColor>
<IsClear>false</IsClear>
</Spread>
</SpreadToList>
</SpreadResultData>
```

Comment: Well, what does line 31 (and the surrounding lines) look like? Posting an example we can comment on would be a good idea

Comment: If you give up after 30 minutes, I suggest trying another profession.

Comment: Interestingly, line 31 in what you post **does not have** a position 27. I strongly suspect there is garbage in your file. Can you upload the **exact** file somewhere?

Comment: @ Marc Gravell Check my file on megafileupload.com/en/file/410345/---Copy-plc.html i am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop

Comment: @RamdasBhosale the file is damaged; see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: with the raw file contents uploaded, the problem becomes clearer. If you look at the last 10 bytes as hex, we get:

```
6C-74-44-61-74-61-3E-EF-BB-BF
```

which is:

```
l  t  D  a  t  a  >
```

where the last 3 bytes are a [zero width no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm).

Fix the bad data at the end of the file and you should be sorted. It should just end:

```
6C-74-44-61-74-61-3E
```

---

Cannot repro; this works fine for me targeting .NET 4.5, using an xml file as per your post; are you sure there isn't anything else after the file? Can you possibly upload the **exact** file somewhere? It is possible there are some contents that aren't visible in the text dump here on SO:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SpreadResultData));
        SpreadResultData data;
        using(var file = File.OpenRead("my.xml"))
        {
            data = (SpreadResultData)ser.Deserialize(file);
        }
    }
}

public class SpreadResultData
{
    public List<Spread> SpreadToList {get;set;}
}
public class Spread
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public string CellPos { get; set; }
    public string CellValue { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int CellLinePos { get; set; }
    public bool IsSetColor { get; set; }
    public bool IsClear { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: check my xml file on http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/410345/---Copy-plc.html